# Using DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer with ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, reactor-kafka

I started looking into using a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` for my kafka consumer factory common error handler. However, it seems that in order to instantiate an instance of this class, 1 option is to pass in a `KafkaOperations<? extends Object, ? extends object> template`. From previous examples, most seem to simply pass in a `KafkaTemplate<>`. However, I am using the reactive version of kafka for both the consumer & producer templates. So, I am not sure if it is somehow possible to use the `ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<>` for this use case?

```
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer( **HERE** ), ...));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The DLPR is not designed for use with the reactive template.

Comment: Any plans to support reactive templates in the future? Or will I need to write my own ?

Comment: The reactive template is a very lightweight wrapper around reactor-kafka. We have no plans for any further enhancement. There's an example of using the DLRP in a non-reactive way from reactor in this issue https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/issues/214#issuecomment-821760338 For the most part, kafka sends are non-blocking (except when fetching metadata).